# Lining up an image with a title

Tags: css, wordpress

I have [this site header](http://www.burnham.school.nz/wordpress/) I'm working on but I can't get the logo and the site title to line up horizontally. I'm relatively new to CSS so would appreciate any hand-holding anyone can offer please ;-)

The logo image is styled with:

```
.logo {
    float:left;
}
```

Whereas the h1.site-title and h2.site-description text is styled thus:

```
 h1.site-title, h2.site-description { 
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 130px; !important
 }
```

I'm pretty sure I need to make another DIV and can't get the positioning right so the logo is at the left, then immediately next to it the site title/description.

Comment: please also show your html or even create a jsfiddle.net (!important want do anything there)

Answer (score 0):

(it should be #logo)  Floating them both left works

```
#logo {
    float: left;
}
.home-link {
    float: left;
}
```

and remove the margin-left

Comment: This is the CSS: #logo { float: left; }
.site-title, .site-description { position:relative; margin-left: 130px;}
 
.site-header .home-link {color: #141412; display: block; margin: 0 auto; width: 75%; max-width: 1080px; min-height: 130px; padding: 0 20px; text-decoration: none; width: 100%;}

.site-header .site-title:hover {text-decoration: none;}

.site-title { font: 600 "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif;font-size: 36px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 1; margin: 0; padding: 20px 0 10px;}

.site-description { font: 300 italic 24px "Source Sans Pro", Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0;}

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that I would recommend changing:

1. In your HTML, you have logo set to an ID, so in your CSS it should use a # instead of a period.
2. You do not need to tag qualify your classes in your CSS, meaning the h1 and h2 are not needed, just .site-title and .site-description should work.
3. Avoid using !important whenever possible. It makes your code very hard to adjust later.
4. instead of working with .site-title and .site-description work with their wrapping container, .home-link. Float both it and #logo left.
5. If you want them to line up side by side, you will have to change the width of home-link to something smaller than 100%.
6. remove the margin-left.

so your CSS would look like this:

```
#logo { float: left; }
.home-link { float: left; width: 75%; }
```

Comment: Hi Joel, thanks. It doesn't appear to work for me following your steps. When I put in .home-link { float: left; width: 75%; } it makes the blue bar fill the top of the page, plus the logo isn't lining up beside the title/description text... what am I doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like the width of 75% is still being overridden by a width of 100%. Without seeing all of your HTML and CSS it is hard to say why. If you would like further help, please make a jsfiddle so we can see the code and work with it from there.

Comment: Hi Joel, sorry I didn't quite understand what a jsfiddle was but think I've got it now - it doesn't quite replicate the original, I'm guessing because it is php/etc.? http://jsfiddle.net/r9JYr/